How to access a translation defined in the base model from views and the admin panel of a child model
In a project I have inherited I have a few polymorphic models based on a common model. Something like:
from django.db import models
from polymorphic.models import PolymorphicManager, PolymorphicModel

class Product(PolymorphicModel):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=127)
    objects=PolymorphicManager()


class Book(Product):
    pass


class Drink(Product):
    pass

Personally, I would not use polymorphism, but it's a bit too late for that and way out of scope. I am tasked with adding translations for the name on the base model using parler, however, the documentation for parler only covers translating fields on the child models.
Nevertheless, I modified the models as such:
from django.db import models
from parler.models import TranslatableModel, TranslatedFields
from parler.managers import TranslatableManager, TranslatableQuerySet
from polymorphic.models import PolymorphicManager, PolymorphicModel
from polymorphic.query import PolymorphicQuerySet

class ProductQuerySet(PolymorphicQuerySet, TranslatableQuerySet):
    pass


class ProductManager(PolymorphicManager, TranslatableManager):
    queryset_class = MarkerQuerySet


class Product(PolymorphicModel):
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        name=models.CharField(max_length=127)

    objects=ProductManager()


class Book(Product):
    pass


class Drink(Product):
    pass

And it seems to work fine in the Django shell:
In [1]: from product.models import Book

In [2]: b0 = Book.objects.first()

In [3]: b0
Out[3]: <Book: A Brief History of Time>

In [4]: b1 = Book()

In [5]: b1.name = 'Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy'

In [6]: b1.save()

In [7]: b2 = Book(name='Slaughterhouse V')

In [8]: b2.save()

When I run my endpoint tests, however, I get a somewhat cryptic error:
.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py:1577: in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter

.
.
.

>       arg, value = filter_expr
E       ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

And a different error when I try to see the admin panel for the child models:
Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field.

I have tried adding a computed properties to the Child models to see if it might fix the admin panel, but it did not. Has anyone any experience with doing something similar?

Perhaps not the problem, but the managers need to be instantiated, so objects=PolymorphicManager()...

@willeM_VanOnsem Yeah, sorry that was a typo I made while simplifying the code, it was instantiated in the original source so I'll just update the question

I should have read the documentation more carefully. It worked once I added PolymorphicParentModelAdmin and PolymorphicChildModelAdmin as base classes to the relevant admin panels and also specified the fields these made available:
ProductAdmin(
    TranslatableAdmin,
    PolymorphicParentModelAdmin,
):
    base_model = Product
    child_models = (Book, Drink)


BookAdmin(
    TranslatableAdmin,
    PolymorphicChildModelAdmin,
):
    base_model = Product
    base_model = Marker
    base_fields = ("name")


DrinkAdmin(
    TranslatableAdmin,
    PolymorphicChildModelAdmin,
):
    base_model = Product
    base_model = Marker
    base_fields = ("name")



